# interface blocks in opengl 3.0

Tags: opengl, glsl

Im trying to use interface blocks in opengl 3.0 (#version 130).
The code looks like following:

```
#version 130

#extension GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object : require

layout(std140) uniform test{
    mat4 testmat;
}
```

This gives me syntax error at std140. Is there an extension I'm missing to enable or it this simply not supported by version 130?

Comment: Did you check that the `GL_EXTENSIONS` string contains `GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object`?

Comment: Yes it is contained!

Comment: Did you miss the semi-colon after the }?

Comment: No just forgot to add it to the question. It compiles well in version 140

Comment: layout(std140) This feature is available only with GLSL Version 1.40 or greater. https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/opengl-programming-guide/9780132748445/app09lev1sec2.html